# Can't figure out how to make files shared between xubuntu and usb

Tags: xubuntu, live-usb, usb-installation, yumi

I just made a brand new xubuntu usb partition with persistent storage on my usb drive, and cannot figure out how to access the files in the root of the usb. Using YUMI, The Xubuntu install works fine, and can do everything, but I cannot find my files. I have tried following this guide https://www.pendrivelinux.com/sharing-files-between-ubuntu-flash-drive-and-windows/#more-1728 but I get stopped when I need to extract initrd.lz. in my version, initrd does not have an extension. I have changed the name to several things, like .lz and .gz, and it does not work either. I am not sure if it is even the correct solution for me. The /cdrom/ directory is read only. Please tell me if you need any extra information.

Comment: When booted on your USB look in `cdrom` for any files stored on the root of the USB. If you are booting an ISO file look in the `isodevice` folder.

Comment: Open your OS ISO file and look in `casper` to find the suffix for `initrd` of the Ubuntu flavor you are using. Most Ubuntu 20.04 flavors use plain old `initrd`. Lubuntu 16.04, (and Mint), use `initrd.lz`. (Debian uses `initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Accessing Data Stored on Persistent USB While Booted from the USB

When booted on your USB, look in the `cdrom` folder for any files stored on the root of the USB. If you are booting an ISO file look in the `isodevice` folder. YUMI uses both `cdrom` and `isodevice` folders, look in YUMI's `isodevice` folder for data first.

These folders are generally read only. Sometimes they can be read/write if opened using `sudo -H nautilus`. Or `Open as Administrator` if it is installed.

### Initrd

If booted from Windows or a Ubuntu internal drive, open your OS ISO file and look in it's `casper` folder to find the suffix for initrd of the Ubuntu flavor you are using.

Or if booted from the Live or Persistent USB look in the `cdrom` or `isodevice` `casper` folder. If using a YUMI USB look for `casper` in `cdrom` first.

Most Ubuntu 20.04 flavors use plain old `initrd`. Lubuntu 16.04, (and Mint), use `initrd.lz`. i386 versions of Ubuntu flavors mainly used `initrd.lz`. (Debian uses `initrd.img-4.19.0-10-amd64` at present).

Comment: The isodevice file was exactly what I needed! thank you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome.